# AWS-Lex Fulfillment with AWS-Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-lex, aws-lex

I have to integrate Amazon lex with Amazon lambda. I came across one problem. I am new at this so please help me. I want to request for a product using Lex.
"**Where can i find meat**"
and Meat will be stored to slot 'SearchProduct'
Then it will search in the database and reply via lex.
Like "i have found Meat in Aisle no 4"

Here i am able to get the value of Aisle no 4 by scanning in the dynamodb but i am not able to send the response.

```
 'use strict';

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: "us-east-1" });
var reply = ' ';


// --------------- Helpers to build responses which match the structure of the necessary dialog actions -----------------------

function elicitSlot(sessionAttributes, intentName, slots, slotToElicit, message, responseCard) {
    return {
        sessionAttributes,
        dialogAction: {
            type: 'ElicitSlot',
            intentName,
            slots,
            slotToElicit,
            message,
            responseCard,
        },
    };
}

function close(sessionAttributes, fulfillmentState, message, responseCard) {
    return {
        sessionAttributes,
        dialogAction: {
            type: 'Close',
            fulfillmentState,
            message,
            responseCard,
        },
    };
}

function delegate(sessionAttributes, slots) {
    return {
        sessionAttributes,
        dialogAction: {
            type: 'Delegate',
            slots,
        },
    };
}



// ---------------- Helper Functions --------------------------------------------------

// build a message for Lex responses
function buildMessage(messageContent) {
    return {
        contentType: 'PlainText',
        content: messageContent,
    };
}



// --------------- Functions that control the skill's behavior -----------------------

/**
 * Performs dialog management and fulfillment for ordering a beverage.
 * (we only support ordering a mocha for now)
 */
function ItemSearch(intentRequest, callback) {

    const outputSessionAttributes = intentRequest.sessionAttributes;
    const source = intentRequest.invocationSource;

    if (source === 'FulfillmentCodeHook') {
        const slots = intentRequest.currentIntent.slots;
        const requestProductName = (slots.SearchProduct ? slots.SearchProduct : null);

        var scanningParameters = {
            TableName: "my table name",
            ProjectionExpression: "#pro, Aisle",
            FilterExpression: "contains (#pro, :productname)",
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                "#pro": "ProductName",
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":productname": requestProductName
            }
        };

        docClient.scan(scanningParameters, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {

                callback(close(outputSessionAttributes, 'Fulfilled', { contentType: 'PlainText', content: 'not found' }));
            }
            else {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.Count == 0) {
                    reply = 'not found';
                    callback(close(outputSessionAttributes, 'Fulfilled', { contentType: 'PlainText', content: 'not found' }));
                }
                else {
                    reply = requestProductName + ' can be found in Aisle No: ' + data.Items[0].Aisle;
                    callback(close(outputSessionAttributes, 'Fulfilled', { contentType: 'PlainText', content: requestProductName + ' can be found in Aisle No: ' + data.Items[0].Aisle }));

                }
            }
        });
    }

    callback(close(outputSessionAttributes, 'Fulfilled', {
        contentType: 'PlainText',
        content: `Thanks for using CoffeeBot! `  // i want the reply from the search here but i always end up with null
    }));
}

// --------------- Intents -----------------------

/**
 * Called when the user specifies an intent for this skill.
 */
function dispatch(intentRequest, callback) {

    console.log(`dispatch userId=${intentRequest.userId}, intent=${intentRequest.currentIntent.name}`);

    const name = intentRequest.currentIntent.name;

    // dispatch to the intent handlers
    if (name.startsWith('Product')) {
        return ItemSearch(intentRequest, callback);
    }
    throw new Error(`Intent with name ${name} not supported`);
}

// --------------- Main handler -----------------------

// Route the incoming request based on intent.
// The JSON body of the request is provided in the event slot.
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    console.log(JSON.stringify(event));

    try {
        console.log(`event.bot.name=${event.bot.name}`);

        // fail if this function is for a different bot
        if (!event.bot.name.startsWith('Aowi')) {
            callback('Invalid Bot Name');
        }
        dispatch(event, (response) => callback(null, response));
    }
    catch (err) {
        callback(err);
    }
};
```

I am getting the reply from the search but i am not able to send the reply to Lex. The content part is always empty.

```
Response:
{
  "sessionAttributes": {},
  "dialogAction": {
    "type": "Close",
    "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled",
    "message": {
      "contentType": "PlainText",
      "content": " "
    }
  }
}
```

Lex will send the slot named 'SearchProduct' ==  'meat'.

[image]

I am not sure at which part i am doing it wrong. Appreciate it if anyone can help  me improve the code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This error is because Amazon Lex expects responses in a certain JSON format. From what looks like you have written the code in Node.js. I am not a node expert but i can provide you a working example of how i send response back to lex.

The flow of the code goes something like this:

> Intent called -> Lambda function invoked -> (Your lamba code runs and
>   process the data given by lex) -> You generate a response to send back
>   to Lex -> Lex reads the Response json and interprets it based on what
>   you have returned.

```
def close(fulfillment_state, message):
response = {
    'dialogAction': {
        'type': 'Close',
        'fulfillmentState': fulfillment_state,
        'message': message
    }
}
return response
response_to_lex =  close('Fulfilled',{'contentType': 'PlainText','content': 'Message i want to send to lex'})
```

The close function creates a "Close" type fullfilment event for lex, and generates an appropriate response message. Note: **type, fulfullmentState, and message** are compulsory parameters that needs to be passed back to lex.

This link can be helpful to understand it in depth: [Lex Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html)

Also looking at the documentation for LEX and Node Lambda at [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/gs2-prepare.html) i can see that the method to call the dispatch function is different. But i could be entirely incorrect here.

Answer (score 0):

You must send the response in a specific format. For Node.js below is the example

```
 const response = {
          dialogAction: {
                        type: "Close",
                        fulfillmentState: "Fulfilled",
                        message: {
                            contentType: "PlainText",
                            content: "i have found Meat in Aisle no 4"
                        }
                    }
                };
                callback(null, response);
```

Can you accept the answer if it's helpful to you?